# How to foreach a select dropdown

Tags: php, html

How to foreach my code in select dropdown so i can less the line of my code.

```
<div class="form-group"> 
                     <label >Procurement Mode</label>
                     <select name='proc_mode'class='form-control'>
                     <option value="">Select Procurement Mode</option>
                     <option value="Public Bidding">Public Bidding</option>
                     <option value="AMP-Shopping">AMP-Shopping</option>
                     <option value="AMP-Small Value">AMP-Small Value</option>
                     <option value="AMP-Direct Contracting">AMP-Direct Contracting</option>
                     <option value="AMP-Repeat Order">AMP-Repeat Order</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the requirement above, try this:

```
<?php 
    $items = array("Public Bidding", "AMP-Shopping", "AMP-Small Value", "AMP-Direct Contracting", "AMP-Repeat Order"); 
?>
<div class="form-group"> 
   <label >Procurement Mode</label>
   <select name='proc_mode'class='form-control'>
     <option value="">Select Procurement Mode</option>
     <?php foreach ($items as $item) { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $item; ?>"><?php echo $item; ?></option>
     <?php } ?>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: so if i want to fetch the record for update so ill just put this in the option value <option value="<?php echo $log->proc_mode;?>"><?php echo $log->proc_mode;?></option>?

Comment: Yes. You can directly loop the database results directly instead of creating a separate array. I had created a separate array to demonstrate the logic to you.

Answer (score 0):

## You can do this in PHP in a certain way. I hope you like it!

This would not work for the first option, however would work for the rest of them.

```php
<?php  
$colors = array("Public Bidding", "AMP-Shopping", "AMP-Small Value", "AMP-Direct Contracting", "AMP-Repeat Order"); 

foreach ($colors as $value) {
  echo "<option value=$value>$value</option> <br>";
}
?>
```